# Android manifest attribute not allowed here

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, manifest

I have several manifest errors regarding some attributes . I have not made any changes to the manifest the application generated automatically yet i get several errors. *( I'm using Android Studio 1.2.2)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.iustinian.girlfriendsolver"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.iustinian.girlfriendsolver.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

-For the xmlns:android attribute i get "URL not registered "
-For android versionCode , versionName , allowBackup , label and theme I get "attribute not allowed here "

I took a look at the manifest documentation and couldn't find an answer . For example the allowBackup attribute is placed exactly like the documentation specifies .

Edit: after looking around some more I found that at android:theme "@style/AppTheme" I get a no resource matches the given name . This is the only thing that shows up in the Gradle Build . I have cleaned and rebuilt the project several times .

Comment: Did you recently switch to Android Studio/Gradle?

Comment: What IDE are you using? I suggest you try cleaning your project and rebuilding, that will usually solve these sorts of strange errors. If this doesn't work, let me know!

Comment: I have just started using Android Studio and playing with android apps  . I did not have any previous projects in Eclipse to say that the migration from one to another could have been the problem.

Comment: Certain attributes that used to be specified in the manifest are now supposed to be specified in your build.gradle file instead.  These include versionCode, versionName, minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion.  If you've already got these in your build.gradle file, you can safely remove them from your manifest.

Comment: That solved the "attribute not allowed here" error . Now I have just the @style/AppTheme problem now . Thank you.

Comment: Also I noticed that although the attributes Michael Krause specified are indeed not in the normal AndroidManifest.xml , when I try to run the app the  they still apear as being put in the debug/AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Just Close your manifest file and reopen it. It worked for me.

Comment: True. Solved at me too.

Comment: Yes worked for me thanks! Amazing that these days we Stackoverflow before trying a simple thing like re-open..

Comment: Simplest answer ever hahah Thanks!

Comment: never been so easy to fix problem

Comment: It not work for me. It happen with generated manifest file in build folder. Every thing become orange. Don't know how to fix it yet. Please help.

Comment: The easiest solution I have seen!

Answer (score 15):

In my case, closing the AndroidManifest.xml AND choosing File > Invalidate Caches / Restart solved the issue.

Not sure why I had to do the last step as well but it sorted out all those errors for me.

Comment: This one fixed my problem Thanks

Comment: worked for me on AndroidStudio thank you

Answer (score 10):

Close AndroidManifest — File — Sync Project with Gradle Files. It helped.

P.S. A few months later I met this problem again — googled — found this answer and it didn't help! :D But this time I removed the Android Studio and installed the beta version. It helped.

Answer (score 6):

In Android Studio just close the Manifest file and open it again. It will solve the issue. By the way Studio gives too many stupid errors like this.

Answer (score 4):

For your "attribute not allowed here" problem, `versionCode`, `versionName` and `allowBackup` have to be placed in the `build.gradle` file and not in the Android Manifest. That should solve the problem.

Secondly, for your "`@style/AppTheme` no resource matches the given name" problem, you will have to check your `styles.xml` file and make sure that a style with the name `AppTheme` exists over there.

Hope this helps you or anyone who views this answer.

Answer (score 3):

This happens when manifest not correctly "recognized" by AndroidStudio: it is correct location file app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml, but not in synthetic AS Android/app/manifests tree left-view.

Just close the project + remove from (welcome)list + re-**import_project (Gradle, Eclipse ADT, etc)**.

Comment: Hi! Could you please be a bit more elaborate on that? What is the "(welcome)list" and what do you mean by "re-import_project"?

Comment: Hi! Could you please be a bit more elaborate on that? What is the "(welcome)list" and what do you mean by "re-import_project"?

Answer (score 3):

In Android Studio -> File -> Syncing Project with Gradle Files, helped me resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Close the andorid studio and open the AndroidManifest.xml from the application folder in any of the local editor for e.g., Notepad,notepad++,sublime etc. Make change and save the manifest file. Now open the androdistudio. Your problem will be solve.

Answer (score 1):

Most Probably, you are modifying the wrong Manifest.xml.
When you attempt to run your code, it creates temporary files which might be what you are editing.

Answer (score 0):

Just open your AndroidManifest.xml file in another editor like notepad++ and apply some changes ,then save it. that might work as a trick!

Answer (score 0):

Simple thing is copy paste backup manifest.xml on the project or save code on notepad and saveas with same manifest.xml and override on old manifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

When you modify certain data in AndroidManifest, it will show an error when you launch the program, and it will also open the **DebugAndroidManifest** file and show errors.

1. Step 1.close the  **Debug AndroidManifes**t  (It will open when you run the code)
2. Step 2. re run the  AndroidManifest