# errors in manifest file after updating the android studio to hedgehog version

Tags: android, android-studio

I was working on an android app which was working fine but as I updated my android studio to the latest version, which is Hedgehog 2023, I started getting bunch of errors in manifest file.

[manifest file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/34kOx.png)

but it's confusing me because when I run the app, it works fine on the emulator, and there are no crashes as before. Why is this happening?

Comment: Try Invalidate Caches

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31683788/android-manifest-attribute-not-allowed-here), you could simply try to close your IDE and reopen.

Worth a try.

Comment: I have done this many times, but it didn't work.